# Jasmine unit test on HTML Element attribute that is changed in setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine unit testing, and I can't seem to wrap my head around this issue, and I wasn't able to find a solution by searching google.

The user clicks the button, which changes the display property from "none" to "block", then resets it to "none" in the setTimeout()

HTML:

```
<div style="display: none" [attr.id]="'copy-tooltip' + rowIndex">VIN Copied</div>
<button (click)="showTooltip(rowIndex)">Show Tooltip<button>
```

TS:

```
showTooltip(index: number){
    var elem = document.getElementById('copy-tooltip' + index);
    elem.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout( () => {
      elem.style.display = "none";
    }, 2500);
}
```

I need to write a unit test that creates a mock HTML element with the id of "copy-tooltip0", then check a) that it sets `display` to "block", and b) that it sets `display` to "none" after the setTimeout(). None of the solutions I've come up with have seemed to work.

Comment: Why not? What did you try?

Comment: I don't have the code anymore since I deleted it when it didnt work, but the closest I got was that it would create a mock HTML element and check the display property after the component function finished executing. So it would only check for "display: none", and not the intermediate "display: block". I couldn't figure out how to detect the intermediary change, so I was hoping someone here would have a more comprehensive solution.